# LDAP Bind failed on docker image php:7.4-apache / bullseye

Tags: php, docker, ldap

I have an application that I wrote in PHP using the docker container php:7.4-apache, however recently the php docker containers have been updated to use Debian Bullseye as the base image.

Ever since this update, I am no longer able to perform LDAP Binds.  No matter what I try it fails and gives me the following error when turning on ldap debugging:

`ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);`

```
TLS: can't connect: (unknown error code).
ldap_err2string
```

There is an issue on Github on the php docker image however it was closed and we were suggested to use the php:7.4-apache-buster image directly.  This does work however it would be nice to figure out what is going on so we can upgrade to the future Bullseye release.

https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/1194

However, just as I was writing this I turned off TLS for ldap and went to the unencrypted 389 port of my LDAP server and it works, so something is wrong with the TLS connection for sure.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.  On Debian Bullseye the **libldap-common** package is not installed when installing **libldap2-dev** as a dependency.  Adding **libldap-common** as a package to install during the build process fixed the issue.

Comment: This also fixed the LDAP authentication for DokuWiki on Bullseye for me.

Comment: This fixed a buster->bullseye upgrade for me, using python-ldap and django-auth-ldap